# Filter FeatureCollection by the number of vertices

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a FeatureCollection of polygons, I was wondering how I filter (remove) polygons that has the number of vertices smaller than a scalar.

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Find Features in a collection whose boundaries contain less than a given number of points.
// Based on example  https://code.earthengine.google.com/cbfc6e6fbe4b8f477d07283307269c12

var max_points = 200;

// Start with a feature collection - in this case US counties.
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection(
    'ft:1pjtcfSKIbYbj4wRcBjc0Bb6NB-sQRI-L2nIzHiU');

// Then  add a property called 'points' to each feature of the collection
// populate it with the number of points in the outer linear ring.
var countiesWithPoints = counties.map(function(f) {
  return f.set({ points  : ee.List(ee.List(ee.Feature(f).geometry().coordinates()).get(0)).length()});

});

var simpleCounties = countiesWithPoints.filterMetadata('points', 'less_than', max_points);
var complexCounties = countiesWithPoints.filterMetadata('points', 'greater_than', max_points);

Map.addLayer(simpleCounties, {color: '900000'});
Map.addLayer(complexCounties, {color: '008000'});

Map.setCenter(-119.7, 38.26, 7);
```

Try it: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7f814a69de1d90a0aed97977eb42969e